# Differentiation - basic areas - calculating the area of grid given line length

Tags: derivatives, area

I'm struggling with this question :

[image: Question]

The part I'm most struggling with is deriving the formula given the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$18x+14y=1512 \implies  y=108-\frac 97 x $$

$$A = 12xy = 12x(108-\frac 97 x) $$